# Ruby Selenium-Webdriver

Tags: ubuntu, selenium

I tried to install Ruby selenium-webdriver but I got this error:

```
sudo gem install selenium-webdriver
[sudo] password for sam: 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing selenium-webdriver:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18/ext/ffi_c
/usr/bin/ruby2.4 -r ./siteconf20170509-10458-cbn64m.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/gems/ffi-1.9.18 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out
```

I've tried different methods that I found from different forums but they didn't work for me.Ruby version is 2.4 and Ubuntu version is 16.04

Comment: You've tried different methods — but what were they?

Comment: I have tried: `apt-get install ruby-dev` , `sudo gem update --system`, `sudo apt-get install make`

Comment: That, as well as the contents of `/var/lib/gems/2.4.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.4.0/ffi-1.9.18/gem_make.out`, should be [edit]ed into the question

Comment: This one solved my problem: `sudo apt-get install ruby2.4-dev`

Comment: Interesting, considering that the unversioned `-dev` package didn't. Don't forget to post that as an answer!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it solved my problem:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.4-dev
```